# If someone engaged in one of the activities that disqualify one from being King or High Priest, without pay, is he still disqualified?

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, malchut-royalty

In Mishneh Torah Laws of Kings and their Wars 1:6 it states ([from Sefaria)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.1.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> ואין מעמידין מלך ולא כהן גדול. לא קצב. ולא ספר. ולא בלן [א.] ולא ברסי. לא מפני שהן פסולין אלא הואיל ואמנותן נקלה העם מזלזלין בהן לעולם. ומשיעשה במלאכה מאלו יום אחד נפסל:
>
> A butcher, barber, bath-attendant or tanner may not be chosen either as a king or as a Kohen Godol (High Priest). Not because they are disqualified, but because these professions are degrading they are always viewed trivially in the eyes of the people. Even if he worked at one of these vocations for but one day, he is disqualified (from becoming king).

If someone for example gave his family member or close friend a haircut without being paid, but merely as a favor, would this cause the degradation the RamBam speaks of?

Note: The Cesef Mishneh states that it has to be done as a "profession", is there anyone else that comments on this?